# RubyMine - Creating the testing folders after initially creating the project without them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

I initially created my project excluding tests and now I want to have tests for my web application. My application is not extensive, but it is big enough such that I don't want to re-start the project.

Is it as simple as creating the folder 'test' in the application directory?

Are there other things I have to adjust in other parts of my program?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One option is just choose a test framework and add it to your app (probably adding just a gem and runing some rake task depending of the framework)

Another option is edit `config/application.rb` and uncomment the line:

```
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

Also you can create an empty rails project and compare your current app with the empty one an copy/modify the files different: Probably just `config/application.rb` and `test/test_helper.rb`